# SQL subquery to find a category in the result

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am getting some data from my database table. The query I use is very simple

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * 
                                FROM mc_boxes_has_categories 
                                WHERE mc_boxes_idmc_boxes = $box_id
                              ");
    $categories = $query->result_array();
    return $categories;
```

The output of this query is a s follows

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [mc_boxes_idmc_boxes] => 12
        [categories_idcategories] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [mc_boxes_idmc_boxes] => 12
        [categories_idcategories] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [mc_boxes_idmc_boxes] => 12
        [categories_idcategories] => 5
    )

)
```

My question is how can I check if the categories contain category id 1 then render 1 view  and if it does not contain then render another view. I need to check for category id 1 somehow is it possible in sql ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want select only those categories which has category 1 change your select query as below:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * 
                                FROM mc_boxes_has_categories 
                                WHERE mc_boxes_idmc_boxes = $box_id AND   categories_idcategories = 1
                              ");
```

And if you want select all categories and then do some different with id 1 categories do this:

```
foreaach($categories as $category)
{
   if($category['categories_idcategories'] == 1)
   {
       // render view 1  
   }
   else
   {
       // render another view
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... As soon as I post my question the solution came to my mind

Comment: Thats grate (I think you are Muslim) may I have your intro.

Comment: yeah i am muslim i am working as student in germnay doing my masters as well in informatics

Comment: @faryal-khan: I am also Muslim and PHP developer, let us share our experiences my skpye id is "corecoder1" or contact me @ core.coder1@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate and group

```
foreach($categories as $row){
    $categories[$row['categories_idcategories']][] = $row['mc_boxes_idmc_boxes'];
}

// whatever compare logic you need
if(isset($categories[1][0])){

}
```